# Biased results when using Method -> "RandomForest" in Predict

Tags: machine-learning

I am interested in using random forests for some prediction, so I have been using `Predict`. I find that `"RandomForest"` method tends to create biased fits of data sets, as demonstrated by predicted vs. actual plots where the slope of the data cloud is not equal to unity; this is unusual for a random forest so I investigated a bit further. An example is below for a small data set:

```
url1 = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5g997u337ysuv1/";
url2 = "exampleRegressionDataForML.m?dl=1";
allData = Import[url1 <> url2]
data = RandomSample[allData];
training = data[[;; Floor[Length[allData]*0.7]]];
validation = data[[Floor[Length[allData]*0.7] + 1 ;;]];
Length[training];
Length[validation];
pTrain = 
  Predict[training, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    Method -> "RandomForest"];
pMeasuresTrain = PredictorMeasurements[pTrain, training];
pMeasuresTrain["ComparisonPlot"]
```

which gives a plot that looks like:

[image: Comparison of predicted and actual values from random forest fitting in Mathematica]

I get the same type of biased fitting for several different data sets. This biased result is not sensitive to the number of trees, number of data points used to determine terminal leaves, or the performance goal (`LeafSize`, `TreenNumber`, and `PerformanceGoal`, respectively). These seem to be all of the levers we have in `Predict` to modify the random forest.

I can run a random forest on the same data set in R and get good results, as shown below (using the randomForest, which wraps [Breiman and Cutler](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/)'s RF package). These un-biased fits in R are robust to perturbation of the additional variables controllable in R such as mtry, etc:

[image: A random forest fit to the data in R shows no bias]

Can anyone explain the source of this bias and how I might go about fixing it? It is difficult to diagnose because `Predict` is somewhat of a black box.

[Etienne Bernard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18554/etienne-bernard) or [Taliesin Beynon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7140/taliesin-beynon) might be interested in this post

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Can anyone explain the source of this bias and how I might go about fixing it?

The source of the bias is the low number of features used to grow the trees (`mtry` in R). Both R and Mathematica currently use `Max[1, Floor[number of features/3]]` as the heuristic for choosing this number (Mathematica might change this in the future). As your data has 5 features, this is an `mtry = 1`. You can change this in Mathematica using

```
    Predict[trainingData, Method -> {"RandomForest", "VariableSampleSize" -> 3}];
```

Plotting this now gives:

[image]

> I can run a random forest on the same data set in R and get good results ... These un-biased fits in R are robust to perturbation of the additional variables controllable in R such as mtry

I think you are a victim of deceptive plots. Lets use `RLink` to generate the R plot with the default `mtry` value (`mtry = 1`):

```
    RSet["input", training[[;;, 1]]];
    RSet["output", training[[;;, 2]]];
    REvaluate["{
     library(randomForest)
     p = randomForest(input, output)
    }"];
    predictedRM = First@REvaluate["predict(p, input)"];
```

Plotting `predictR` versus `training[[;;, 1]]`, I get:

[image: The predictor performance using R package randomForest]
Now combine the plot above with the Mathematica plot for `"VariableSampleSize" -> Automatic`: Red dots are from R, blue from Mathematica.

[image]

They give virtually identical results! (although one wouldn't expect them to be exactly the same, given the randomness inherent in the method).

The R plot you gave is probably generated with `mtry = 3`: [image]

Combine the R `mtry = 1` (blue) and `mtry = 3` plots:
[image]

This demonstrates that the result is indeed very sensitive to `mtry` (or equivalently the Mathematica option `"VariableSampleSize"`).

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian! I guess I mist have absentmindedly set mtry = 3 in R without realizing it.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you found out about the `"VariableSampleSize" -> 3` option? It must be a silly question but…?

Comment: @chris among other ways, the simplest is `PredictorInformation[p, "Options"]` which gives the full form of the method used, so it is quite useful.

Comment: @Sebastian, it appeasrs that "VariableSampleSize" is no longer a valid option?